# How to figure out which UMS thread is currently blocked?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, scheduling

When the user-mode scheduler gets invoked as a result of a UMS thread blocking (i.e. [`UmsSchedulerThreadBlocked`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/nc-winnt-rtl_ums_scheduler_entry_point)), is there a way to figure out *which* thread has blocked?

Comment: Wouldn't it necessarily be the current one?

Comment: @user253751: the question is how do you get the `PUMS_CONTEXT` for it? (Note the "current" thread at that point is the scheduler thread.)

Comment: According to [`UmsSchedulerThreadBlocked`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/nc-winnt-rtl_ums_scheduler_entry_point#remarks), 
when a UMS worker thread that is running on the scheduler thread yields or blocks, the system calls the scheduler thread's entry point function with a pointer to the UMS thread context of the worker
thread.

And 
If the Reason parameter is UmsSchedulerThreadBlocked, bit 0 of this parameter indicates the type of activity that was being serviced when the UMS worker thread blocked.
Maybe the pointer reside in the other bits.

Comment: @YangXiaoPo: I've already checked, the pointer isn't passed. That's why I asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only method I can think of is to track it manually every time the scheduler calls `ExecuteUmsThread`.